# Check if there's a line break after a ">" (closing HTML-Tag)

Tags: php, html, string

I'm looking for a way to check, if there is a line break after the ">"-char of a HTML-Tag.

My code should do the following: 
Go to the ">"-char and check if the next char is a line break (\r or \n). If not, add a line break.

At the moment I'm just replacing the ">"-char:

```
$fileName = $link;
$string = file_get_contents($link);
$result = str_replace(">", ">\r\n", $string);
file_put_contents($fileName, $result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead:

```
$result = preg_replace("/>(?!\r|\n)/",">\r\n",$string);
```

Check the [PCRE Assertions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Comment: Please note that `>\n\n\n` would be transformed into `>\r\n\n\n\n`.